# Use bash to cut lines in one file to lengths explicitly stated in another

Tags: bash, awk, cut

I have one file that is a list of numbers, and another file (same number of lines) in which I need the length of each line to match the number of the line in the other file. For example:

file 1:

```
5
8
7
11
15
```

file 2:

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

output:

```
abcde
abcdefgh
abcdefg
abcdefghijk
abcdefghijklmno
```

I've tried using awk and cut together but I keep getting the error "fatal: attempt to use array `line' in a scalar context". I'm not sure how else to go about this. Any guidance is much appreciated!

Comment: Show your code so we can help you find that error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

awk is your tool for this: one of

```
# read all the lengths, then process file2
awk 'NR == FNR {len[NR] = $1; next} {print substr($0, 1, len[FNR])}' file1 file2
```

```
# fetch a line from file1 whilst processing file2
awk '{getline len < lenfile; print substr($0, 1, len)}' lenfile=file1 file2
```

Comment: Both of these seem to work great! Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 3):

`awk` is probably more appropriate, but you can also do:

```
while read line <&3; do 
    read len <&4; echo "${line:0:$len}"; 
done 3< file2 4< file1
```

Comment: `while IFS= read -u3 -r line && IFS= read -u4 -r len` -- need to empty IFS and use -r to get the lines verbatim from the file.

Answer (score 2):

another `awk`

```
$ paste file1 file2 | awk '{print substr($2,1,$1)}'

abcde
abcdefgh
abcdefg
abcdefghijk
abcdefghijklmno
```

Comment: This is awesome, but you will run into trouble if "$2" contains whitespace.

Comment: Yes, in that case you can set field delimiter to tab.

Comment: The trouble is there's no way to know what FS is safe, as we don't know the contents of file2. awk uses `\034` as the SUBSEP value which may be safe.

Answer (score 0):

Using Perl

```
perl -lne ' BEGIN { open($f,"file1.txt");@x=<$f>;close($f) } 
             print  substr($_,0,$x[$.-1]) ' file2.txt
```

with the given inputs

```
$ cat cmswen1.txt
5
8
7
11
15

$ cat cmswen2.txt
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz

$  perl -lne ' BEGIN { open($f,"cmswen1.txt");@x=<$f>;close($f) } print  substr($_,0,$x[$.-1]) ' cmswen2.txt
abcde
abcdefgh
abcdefg
abcdefghijk
abcdefghijklmno

$
```

Comment: it feels wrong to call out to cat from perl: `open $f, "<", "cmswen1.txt"; @x = <$f>; close $f`

Comment: thanks @glennjackman, yes I also felt same.. just the habit of writing short answers is overpowering me :-).. anyways updated...